# Comparability of the dependent variable measure over time

Tags: regression, estimation, measurement

I need to estimate the effect of several educational policies that were implemented over 20 years on schools performance. School performance is measured as percentage of pupils who pass the exam at the end of compulsory schooling. However the exam has been changed at several points over time. Is there a way to take that into account in my regression analysis? In the estimated equation I am also including year dummies.